# Rating results after searching from a database

Tags: java, sql, database, search

I have a system where people inputs some words and based on this I have to search into a database of products. The products belongs to one category and have attributes such as brand,price,condition (new, old,used..)

Does someone knows how to sort a list of results according to best match i.e. those which match words entered by the user should appear first

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515099/text-indexing-algorithm/4515232#4515232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use [Zend Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html), you'll find a quick intro on [this Symfony framework page](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/17).

Edit: as you are using Java, try the [original Lucene library](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) (Zend Lucene is actually a port to PHP).

Comment: I am currently using GWT and Java on the server

Comment: Lucene is actually originally a Java library. You'll find it easily using your favorite search engine.