# How is Gmail search is so fast?

Tags: php, mysql

What is the most efficient way to search through so many characters? What do you think?

Let's say website built in PHP and MySQL.

What should I learn to be able to build this as much efficiently as possible? Are there any algorythms I should learn or something?

Comment: Highly paid engineers with PhD's, and lots of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Text indexing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515099/text-indexing-algorithm/4515232#4515232)

Answer (score 1):

Google uses a custom-made database solution called BigTable, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_table, which is run linked over hundreds of servers all over the world. So they're fast because they wrote the software specifically to be fast, and set up the hardware in such a way that they could squeeze the most out of it.

You can get to a decent set with PHP and MySQL, but once you start dealing with very large data sets, MySQL, and any other generic database, will start to buckle under the stress. If you want to learn more about this, a good place to start is to do a search for concurrency in database design (briefly explained in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control amongst others), which is a topic way too large to cover in a stackoverflow reply =)

Answer (score 0):

Google goes beyond simply optimizing the databases and the code. They also do a lot of distributed programming. While the exact mechanisms they use to power systems such as Gmail are guarded secrets, it is known that they have entire farms of computers networked, each working on parts of the index at any given time, rather than just one server.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, look at the [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

This is assuming your content is stored in the database (such as in a CMS).