# how to build a gmail style search in django?

Tags: django, search

I want to build a gmail style search app for my site with configurable operators and entities. For example, gmail lets you type from: and then searches your email records by the from attribute.  I want to do the same, but with e.g. ticket milestones or product descriptions, etc.

Any suggestions on how to get started? Should I try to leverage an existing project like django-haystack? Or should I try rolling my own, using more basic django features?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6005569/272861

Comment: would you mind elaborating on how that link relates to my problem, specifically?  thanks.

Comment: You might be better off looking at a search server like Apache Solr http://lucene.apache.org/solr/ - it offers much of feature-set you need out of the box and scales superbly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be fairly easy to implement in haystack - SearchQuerySets have a filter method much the same as django's querysets which you could use to filter on your custom parameters. Have a look at the [searchqueryset docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html) for more.

To actually build the app, I'd write a custom SearchForm which parses parameter:value parts out of the query value, uses them to filter or search on the relevant attribute, and then uses any remaining keywords to search as per normal on the filtered searchqueryset (using SearchQuerySet.auto_query)

Comment: Any recommendations for operator and result autocomplete, like "from: someemail"?

Comment: I've never done partial string autocomplete, but I have found jquery-ui really good and it looks like you'll be able to use that. See http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple for an example.